# Caching images in Swift?

Tags: swift, caching

I'm downloading images and displaying them each time the user visits a particular view. To make it more efficient I want to start caching so instead of fetching from the database the user already has the images downloaded.

From my research I found a bunch of Swift libraries that handle caching for you, such as [HanekeSwift](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift), [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher), and [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke). I'm wondering what the difference is between using one of these libraries and just downloading the image to Core Data.

As far as I know, the first time a user downloads the images I can just save them to Core Data and check if they exist by key the next time. Are there any advantages to using one of these libraries instead?

Comment: Why store images in Core Data? Save them as files.

Comment: I didn't know you could just save files, are you talking about something like this? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file-using-uiimagepngrepresentation

Comment: If you just want the images in memory for the duration of the app, use NSCache as NSCache<String, Data>, just store it as NSData/Data and render it with the UIImage(data:_)

Comment: Simply write the downloaded data to a file.

Comment: @hooliooo I need these images cached for every time the user access the app.

Comment: @rmaddy I wasn't aware that iOS had files

Comment: How could it not have files? iOS is a full Unix based OS.

Comment: @rmaddy do you have an example or documentation I can look up? Thanks

Comment: a Benchmark from nuke compared to other libraries https://github.com/kean/Image-Frameworks-Benchmark

Comment: here is an older article (one year old) but the current status maybe changed. Section "When Should You Use Nuke?" in [Ray Wenderlich: What is... Nuke](https://www.raywenderlich.com/118361/what-is-nuke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't save images to core data. You should save them to files and then if you want you can store the path or file name or other attributes about the image in core data. You can save the images to your apps documents directory for instance with the following code.

```
let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String

if let filePath = dir.stringByAddingPathComponent("filename.png"){
  try? UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
}
```

If you want to save to a sub folder just use FileManager to make sure the sub folder has been created and create it if not.

Comment: Would I need to store data about the image in Core data f I wanted to search for it later on, assuming I have the name of the image?

Comment: yes  and better a uuid. dont save path also because the full path changes alwas

Comment: @MarksCode well you can use an attribute of the user as the file name as an alternative. For instance if the user has a username you can name it `"\(user.username).png"` and just look up if a file by that name exists in your image directory. If you want to store more data on the image than just if it exists or not then store the attributes in core data like imageWidth or imageHeight upon saving an image.

Comment: @JoseCastellanos Each image I plan on saving is going to have a name I'll be able to access at anytime, does that mean I can just look it up using that name? I don't really understand what people are saying by `full path changes`?

Comment: @MarksCode yes if you know the name you can access it anytime without the need for core data. Don't worry about the "full path changing". What @muescha means is that the full path to your application's directory changes so `let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String` will be different every time so not to store that part in core data and instead store something like "images/filename.png" to core data that gets added on to the dir string (that changes) if that makes sense